# Set SIM PIN in /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: raspbian, modem, networkmanager

I've a Huawei E3372 usb modem and works out of box when I connected in my Raspbian Strech.
With others Huawei modems I needed vwdial setting up, but with E3372 seems it not use wvdial to up network interface.
My problem is the following, if the sim has a pin I don't know where to configure the pin. I've try to adding the pin in /etc/network/interface like that

```
iface eth1 inet dhcp
  wwan-apn gprs-service.com
  wwan-pin 1234
```

But not work. Just work if the SIM has no PIN.
The 'ifconfig' command shows same autoconfig information

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.8.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.8.255
    inet6 fe80::ccb:57c9:e52f:80f7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 442  bytes 88172 (86.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 442  bytes 63307 (61.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         hi.link         0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 eth1
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 eth1
```

Where is the configuration file when the usb modem is setting up automatically?

Thanks

EDIT:
dmesg information about modem connected

```
[    6.981393] usb 1-1.1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[    7.112560] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc
[    7.112574] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    7.112584] usb 1-1.1.2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[    7.112592] usb 1-1.1.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[    7.178518] usb-storage 1-1.1.2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    7.178902] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.1.2:1.2
[    7.249224] cdc_ether 1-1.1.2:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.2, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[    7.249487] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    8.235391] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[    8.235863] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    8.236833] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```